# Limit of function with taylor series

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying very hard to understand the limits with the help of taylor expansion but i still stuck in it ,

$$\lim _{x\to 0^+}\left(e^{\frac{x^2-1}{x}}\right)$$
if I apply the taylor expansion
$$1+\frac{x^2-1}{x}+\frac{\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x}\right)^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ 
then applying limit as $x\to 0^+$ will give $\infty$ (infinity) but if i do with limit chain rule i am getting right answer which is **$0$**.

Comment: You shouldn't have $x^3$ in that remainder term. Also why are you trying to use Taylor expansions? It's not useful here.

Comment: hello sir i am kind of curious where i can use taylor or simple limit calculations thats why i getting confused again and again

Comment: Generally you would only use it if the remainder term does, in fact, go to zero sufficiently fast so that we may only concern ourselves with the first $n$ terms.

Comment: in our exam we have make qualitative graph , then if i use taylor ; it will surely make my question wrong , but some time it is helpful in many situation

Comment: As with anything, it requires practice and experience for most. For this example, if you write out the next term, you will see that it will diverge, and with every additional term, you will find greater and greater divergence, which is a clear sign that you should not try to Taylor expand. Simply put, it has to converge at the point of interest, but it does not here.

Comment: if limit goes to infinity should i always kept in mind the divergence situation?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: if i have a function which limit goes to infinity should i always kept in mind the divergence situation? A function of any family of function ; ( poly , exp , trig)

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. If you have a completely different question, you should post it as such in full as a separate question.

Comment: got it sir , i will take this advice , thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a correction: The Taylor expansion (around zero) of the exponential is

$$e^z = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2} + O(z^3)$$

Then, in your case you'd get

$$e^{(x^2-1)/x}= 1 + \frac{x^2-1}{x} + \frac{(x^2-1)^2}{2x^2} + O((\frac{x^2-1}{x})^3)$$

But this lead us nowhere. Because we are not interested in $z \to 0^+$, but in $x\to 0^+$ , which implies $z\to -\infty$

Then, it's as simple as recalling $\lim_{z\to -\infty} e^z =0$

Comment: Yes, but this is not a Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is not a Taylor series but the start of the infinite series representation of $e^z$.

May be simpler would be
$$y=e^{\frac{x^2-1}{x}}\implies \log(y)=\frac{x^2-1}{x}=x-\frac 1x$$ making
$$\lim _{x\to 0^+} \log(y)=-\infty\implies\lim _{x\to 0^+}y=0$$